# Vercel App Domain as a web domain in facebook app

Tags: facebook, next.js, vercel, facebook-apps

[image: Facebook Problem]

Hello, I have a vercel app hosted in https://next-ui-integration.vercel.app domain, but when I try to add the domain to my facebook app, because I'll need facebook integration facebook doesn't let me add any vercel domains, anyone knows why is this happening?

when I host my app in other sites such as firebase I can add the domain, but I need the vercel hosting

Comment: It looks like you tried to include https://. https:// is not part of the domain. Try `next-ui-integration.vercel.app`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the url for the website integration in the login product should be the same as the app domains